# Get detailed report from AWS COST EXPLORER API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Using AWS Cost Explorer API, if i use request:

```
GetCostAndUsageRequest request = new GetCostAndUsageRequest();
request.setTimePeriod(interval);
request.setGranularity("MONTHLY");

Expression expression = new Expression();
 
DimensionValues dimensionValues = new DimensionValues();
dimensionValues.setKey("LINKED_ACCOUNT");
dimensionValues.setValues(Collections.singletonList(accountId));

expression.setDimensions(dimensionValues);
request.withFilter(expression);
request.setMetrics(Arrays.asList("AmortizedCost","BlendedCost","NormalizedUsageAmount", "UnblendedCost", "UsageQuantity"));
```

All i do si receive the number representing AmortizedCost etc. So it is the total cost,usage etc ( specified by metrics).

However how can i  retrieve DETAILED report using cost explorer api?

I have multiple EC2 instnace running, so for example for each of the instance i would like to recieve

> | productCode| | product name |    |UsageType           |
> |Operation      |     AmazonEC2       Amazon Elastic Compute   | description |
> | usagq quantity|  |currency|  | cost before tax| | TAX|
> |TAX TYPE|    |TOTAL |

basicly for each instance individual report. How is something like this possible? If i use getDimensionValues(), alli can get is list of all dimensions i can use, but that tells me nothing.

Comment: Did you try [getCostAndUsageWithResources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_GetCostAndUsageWithResources.html)? You would have to combine this with the getDimensionValues to parse out values for each dimension.

Comment: yes it returns the same values and only has time span of 14 days ( i need 30 )